# NodeJS - Stream MP3 Audio Playlist from fixed HTTP endpoint

Tags: node.js, audio, ffmpeg, streaming, mp3

I'd like to stream a playlist of mp3 audio files from a fixed HTTP endpoint on my server, e.g. http://localhost/stream.mp3. I am dynamically generating a number of mp3 files, so when I setup this fixed endpoint, I don't yet have a complete list of the audio files I want to broadcast.

Is there a way in which I can generate this kind of fixed streaming endpoint and start with one file, and then queue up the rest as I continue to generate them? I'm using NodeJS/Express as my web-server, and generating my audio files with FFMPEG.

Answer (score 1):

On the server side you can add the mp3 files to a directory and serve them as static files.

On the client side you can have your client poll the directory on the server for the new mp3s added or create an API on the server which will return a list of the URL's of newly added mp3s. The client can then play them in order, based on a naming convention or on the date etc.

You could also use a m3u playlist and add all the mp3's that exist at a given time to the playlist. When a particular mp3 is about to finish you can then reload the m3u playlist and it will have all the latest ones also.

This does involve having to request the playlist again, but it is a very small file. HLS and DASH video streams can use a similar approach for Live.

Having a single mp3 file as the source and adding new mp3 to it dynamically as you work will prove tricky I think, as each mp3 will have a header. These headers may have different bitrates and timing info also so you can't just remove them. There are tools which would allow you concatenate mp3 on the server side (e.g. http://mp3wrap.sourceforge.net) and you could then work out the correct place to serve the next byte range to the player, but it would be worth being 100% sure the other techniques above would not work for you as they would likely be a lot easier.

Comment: Not exactly my goal. I know that this can be done, but I want to send it as one continuous stream to the HTML5 audio element from a fixed endpoint as mentioned above. I don't want the client to be polling for mp3 files.

Comment: Ok - added some more info above. Its worth noting that ultimately, all HTTP based methods involve the client requesting the content, generally in chunks, so a lot of the mechanisms are based on this or leverage this.